# 2 API Calls in One JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, asynchronous

presently I am attempting to make 2 different api calls one after the other within 1 java/nodejs script.  It seems after my first function runs successfully, the second one errors with the following:

FetchError: request to  failed, reason: socket hang up;
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET'

Below is a code snippet of what I have tried thus far:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const formData = require("form-data");
const fs = require("fs");
//const express = require("express");
var apiName = "<LOCAL SYSTEM FILE TO UPLOAD>";
var lookupName = "<LOCAL SYSTEM FILE TO UPLOAD>";
var accessToken = "Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>";
var url = '<URL API #1>';
var url2 = '<URL API #2>;
var headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': accessToken,
};


const form = new formData();
const buffer2 = fs.readFileSync(lookupName);
const buffer = fs.readFileSync(apiName);


    const uploadAPI = function uploadAPI() {
        form.append("Content-Type", "application/octect-stream");
        form.append('file', buffer);

        fetch(url, {method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: form})
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    };



const uploadLookup = function uploadLookup() {
    form.append("Content-Type", "application/octect-stream");
    form.append('file', buffer2);

    fetch(url2, {method: 'PUT', headers: headers, body: form})
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
};



if (!apiName !== true) {
    uploadAPI()
} else {}

if (!lookupName !== true) {

    console.log("Uploading Lookup File");
    uploadLookup()
} else {}
```

I tried using a "setTimeout" function which does not seem to work as I would have liked it to.  My best guess is each API call would need to be it's own separate socket connection?  Any help with getting me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.all([
    fetch(url),
    fetch(url2)
]).then(function (res) {
        // Get a JSON object from each of the responses
        return res.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        // do something with both sets of data here
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // if there's an error, log it
    });
```

Comment: this is a clever usage.  I will tool around with it to get it working.  Presently, using "Promise.all" still only executes the first asnyc API call, then errors on the second with the same message I posted in the original post.

Comment: Your use of `res` here is not correct.  In this example, `res` will be an array of results from the two `fetch()` operations.  You can't do `res.json()` when `res` is an array.